# Gettting the last Commit from AWS Codecommit for using GetDIfferences() call

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk

I am trying to get the names of folders of code that has changed in an AWS Codecommit repository.  I can achieve what I want by using the following Git command; however I am not allowed to use that for my project:

```
git diff --name-only head head~1
```

I am only allowed to use an AWS SDK to perform this functionality. And per the [docs](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/codecommit.html#CodeCommit.Client.get_differences) you must explicitly pass the BeforeCommit and AfterCommit fields. I have tried passing the following args and they do not work:

```
response = client.get_differences(
    repositoryName="My-repo-name",
    beforeCommitSpecifier="HEAD~1",
    afterCommitSpecifier="HEAD"
)
```

The above code does not work because it does not accept using HEAD~1.  Is another way to obtain the beforeCommitSpecifier?

Comment: Have you tried using `HEAD^1`?

Comment: @Paolo yes that does not work

Comment: If `HEAD` works, `HEAD` with suffixes should usually work as well. The usual reason they wouldn't is if something made a *shallow clone*. In that case you wouldn't be able to get the diff at all anyway. But it's possible they've done a really poor job here and you have to use a raw hash ID: if so, this is an AWS issue, not a Git one.

Comment: As a side note, while typing `head` in lowercase tends to work on WIndows and macOS, it's a bad habit to get into, because (1) it doesn't work on Linux and (2) it produces the wrong result when you start using added work-trees (with `git worktree add`).